# Current page highlighting in menu in aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, menu

I want to highlight the current page. tried this code but is not working.. any help would be thankful and appreciated..

```
$(function() {
    $("#site-menu li a").click(function() {
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        //"this" is the element clicked on
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });
});​
```

```
<div id="menu">
     <ul id="site-menu">
          <li><a href="Home_Page.aspx">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Services.aspx">services</a></li>
          <li><a href="About_Us.aspx">about us</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact_Us.aspx">contact us</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When you click on your anchor links, the location is changed, why do you want to add a class to them on click?

Comment: @undefined.. Maybe the Menu was on the masterPage

Comment: yup menu s on master page.. any alternate..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start with that:

```
$(function() {
    var curPage = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $("#site-menu li a[href='" + curPage + "']").addClass("current");
});​
```

Just improve this script to work correctly with default page (I think it's gonna be Home_Page.aspx), when it doesn't appear in URL.

Comment: http://localhost:49169/HirenSir/Services.aspx   this must give me Services.aspx.. how can I get that..

Comment: `location.pathname` contains "HirenSir/Services.aspx". We cut the part after last slash and check what menu link have _exactly_ this value in its `href` attribute. If your links contain full path (HirenSir/Services.aspx or even localhost:49169/HirenSir/Services.aspx) you should improve my script. I wrote it basing on information from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $("#site-menu li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        //"this" is the element clicked on
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });
});​
```

Also make sure you have **.current** class in your CSS
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/q2NEK/1/)

Seems to be working when I used e.preventDefault();.

Maybe the class was being rendered back to default HTML on postback..

Comment: links didn't worked after i kept your code but it did matched the last clicked element.. if you could help with it... and am new to it so if you could show the complete structure and where it should be placed.. thanks

Comment: That is because of e.preventDefault() which stops the links from transferring to a different page

Comment: Is your menu in the MasterPage

Comment: yup menu s on master page.. any alternate..!!

Comment: check @Smileek post.. That should be easier to achieve than handle them after postbacks

Answer (score 0):

I've create a fiddle here showing a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/psDBP/

try this (see my comments too):

```
$(function() {
    // change to on rather than deprecated click
    $("#site-menu li a").on("click", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); // stops the a href firing
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        //"this" is the element clicked on
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try

```
    $("#site-menu li a").live('click',function() {
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        //"this" is the element clicked on
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });
```

inside your `$(document).ready(function(){})`;

Comment: I am not a downvoter, but you should know that `.live` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 (http://api.jquery.com/live/). You should use `.on` or `.delegate' instead.